# Pass & display the same view from VC1 to VC2

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, mapbox

I have a view (in my case a MGLMapview : mapboxView) which is displayed in my first VC. I want my second VC to display the same view.

So from VC1 to VC2 I did :

```
self.VC2.mapView = self.mapView

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.VC2, animated: true)
```

Then in the viewDidLoad of VC2 :

```
view.addSubview(mapView)
```

My problem is that nothing appears.
However, when I print the size & height of the mapView in second VC, it is not zero.

Do I miss something ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: How did you create the view? In any case, the issue most probably is that you need to copy the view itself to your other VC, since by calling `view.addSubview(mapView)` you just display the `mapView`, but when you actually push `VC2`, `VC1` might get unloaded from memory and hence the `mapView` object itself might get destroyed as well.

Comment: You can push same view controller rather than creating a new one. 


`self.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.VC1, animated: true)`

Comment: How do you pass your map view? Is it from prepare for segue or something? How did you connect vc1 to instance of vc2 you want to push?

Another thing to you need to lookup the rect of your map view relative to vc2's view. Please provide more code.

Comment: Add `self.mapView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` in VC2 after `view.addSubview(mapView)`. This will solve the issue

Comment: @Priya it didn't work. But the validate answer explained why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've asked myself this question too. I don't know if it's possible (I never found a way to do it) but it's not recommended. Once you put a view into a view controller (via `addSubview` on its `view`), the view controller "owns" the view.

Here's the [`UIView` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview) that explains why:

> Views can be nested inside other views to create view hierarchies, which offer a convenient way to organize related content. Nesting a view creates a parent-child relationship between the child view being nested (known as the subview) and the parent (known as the superview). **A parent view may contain any number of subviews but each subview has only one superview.**

Instead, add the properties you need to set up a new map view in VC2 (for example center, span, any annotation details) and set up a new map view in the second view controller.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply. I wanted to avoid the creation of a new object map to be more efficient & less consuming. But if it's the only way ..

Comment: This says a subview can only have one superview, but it doesn't specify it should only have one superview for its lifecycle. I'm looking for the same solution even using MGLMapView as well.  The maps are really slow to load their styles upon intialization and it feels like a poor UX.  I already have an initialized map, it seems silly I'd need to initialize a whole new one to display slightly different info on a different screen.

Comment: @JakeT. If you get it to work please add an answer here. If you can't get it to work with a bare view, you might also try wrapping the view in a "custom container view controller" and using `addChildViewController:`, `removeFromParentViewController` etc to transfer it.